# Why does printing a static variable value gives error in static block while assigning it doesn't

Tags: java, static-initialization, static-block

```
public class ABC {


    static {       
       System.out.println(i);
    }

    static int i=10;

    static {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(3);

        ABC a = new ABC();
    }
}
```

gives error;

```
can not reference a field before it is defined
```

But following -

```
public class ABC {
    static {       
        i=20;
        System.out.println(ABC.i); 
        System.out.println(i); //same error as above
    }

    static int i=10;

    static {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        System.out.println(3);

        ABC a = new ABC();
    }
}
```

doesn't throw any error and compiles and runs fine. Even if I use,

```
package com.sample.package2;

public class ABC {

    static {  
        System.out.println(ABC.i);
    }

    static int i=10;

    static {
        System.out.println("yahan 10" + i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(3);

        ABC a = new ABC();
    }
}
```

runs fine. Confused as why this error is coming up. There are similar questions asked and it might sound duplicate to some of you but haven't found a clear answer on it yet. What is the order of initialization. I believed static block executes first before anything else. If I shift the `static int i=10;` error goes away. Does static variable initialize before static blocks?

Comment: Irrelevant fun fact: seems with this question we now have 1,250,000 questions tagged java. And no, I am not giving you a box of chocolatres … :-)

Comment: Sorry about that, will try to refine. I can surely give you some chocos if you could help me understand what's going on here : )

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about. We love questions.

Answer (score 0):

What you have used is called as " *static initialization block* ". If you have read [the documentation of initializing fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), you will encounter the following (emphasis on mine)

> A class can have any number of static initialization blocks, and they can appear anywhere in the class body. **The runtime system guarantees that static initialization blocks are called in the order that they appear** in the source code.

In your code, you have declared and initialized `i` *after* trying to call it. If you have done that *before* the static initialization, the variable `i` is then not defined.

```
static {       
   System.out.println(i); // <-- where is i ?
}

static int i=10;
```

The use of `ABC.i` before defining the `i` in the class works because when you are calling `ABC`, the class `ABC` is being initialized. You have to look at when an initialization occurs. If you check [JLS 12.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1), you will notice

> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> *...omitted...*
>
> A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable
>
> *...omitted...*

which means that `ABC` is being initialized. However, during the initialization, the `static { ... }` methods are **not** called anymore because it's used one time. Here, the error isn't thrown. Hence it is possible to retrieve the assigned value when calling `ABC.i` in the `static { ... }` method, even if `i` is defined *after* that method.

Comment: Please take a look at second snippet. It gives error while printing `i` and not in `ABC.i`. how come if we go by this definition?

Comment: @AnujSingh had to dig in the JLS specs to to explain why `ABC.i` works. Updated the answer.

Comment: @KareIG, then how come static `{i=20; System.out.println(ABC.i);}` works and prints 20?

Answer (score -1):

```
static {       
   System.out.println(i);
}

static int i=10;
```

You are intializing the variable later but calling it before.So it throws an error
 wheras

```
static {       
    i=20;
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

and

```
  static {  
    System.out.println(ABC.i);
}

static int i=10;
```

i is initialized first then it is called.

Comment: How come `i=20` in second snippet not giving it

Comment: All the static variables are initialized first. So I is already intilized with 20 before System.out.println.

Comment: there is no declaration if we go by your logic, hence there should be an error. Declaration comes after initialization.

Comment: see my edit, your logic doesn't work. have given it a lot of thought already. if it was that simple, wouldn't have asked here : )

Comment: public static void main is executed first so ABC is initialized. So i is initliazed .When you call ABC.i it does not throw any error but when u call only System.out.println(i) it throws an error because it is not yet declared and initialized. ABC.i is a static variable in ABC class so even if no value is initiliazed it will give 0 and not throw any error.

Comment: Do you mean `i` in static block is not treated in a static way without `ABC`? Do you mean its a local variable?

Comment: @AnujSingh yes its a local variable

Comment: Then, how come its not throwing error for declaration?

Comment: static {       
        i=20;
        System.out.println(ABC.i); 
        System.out.println(i); //same error as above
    } your declaring the variable after this static block so the error is thrown

Comment: static {       
      int  i=20;
        System.out.println(TEST.i); 
        System.out.println(i); 
    } use this thr wont be any error since ur declaring the variable before .

Comment: We aren't on same page it seems. `static{i=5;System.out.println(ABC.i);System.out.println(i);}` why is error not thrown on `ABC.i` but only on `i` and moreover, no error is thrown on `i=5;`, this is the line where in i meant without declaration. And this is the first static block.